# ASP.NET C# Sending Information Back to Client While Processing Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, long-polling

Not sure if I'll explain this properly but here goes. I having written an asp.net app using C# for the code behind. After the user makes some selection and hits the "run" button I pass off the processing to a dll written in C# but what I want is a way to periodically send information back to the client so they can see what's going on like how many records have been processed and things like that. How can I accomplish this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Provide feedback to the user on Long Running Tasks – using loader image - MS AJAX and JQuery](http://msmvps.com/blogs/shahed/archive/2009/10/27/asp-net-mvc-asp-net-tips-provide-feedback-to-the-user-on-long-running-tasks-using-loader-image-ms-ajax-and-jquery.aspx)

Also: [How Do I: Use the ASP.NET AJAX UpdateProgress Control?](http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/video-123.aspx)

Comment: Neither of those solutions provide feedback from the server during the operation, do they?  Aren't they just showing a loader image (such as an animated "in progress" graphic) to the client, while waiting for the server to respond?

Comment: it doesn't sound like this is the solution. It sounds like RickNZ says to just show that the server is processing but no feedback.

Comment: did you take a look at the second part of the article in the first link?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of accomplishing this kind of task. I am presenting a few ideas

**Solution 1:**

You can use Ajax [Timer Control.](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/IntroToTimerControl.aspx)

**Solution 2:**

Make a [Windows Service](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007AM/window_service.aspx) that will read the information and will interact with the asp.net application to notify about the requested information. It will act as a background worker.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This may have been my wording of the question but I found what I was looking for. You can use the HttpResponse.Flush method to achieve what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is often called [HTTP Server Push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_streaming) or *HTTP Streaming* or *Long Polling*. Depending on how it's done.

You can also check out this SO question on HTTP Streaming...

[Cross-browser implementation of "HTTP Streaming" (push) AJAX pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112413/cross-browser-implementation-of-http-streaming-push-ajax-pattern)

Or this one with an example of *Long Polling*

[How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/long-polling