# On the clientside, how do I listen for external changes on the server?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, callback, xmlhttprequest

I'm certain this has been asked before so I'm ready for a torrent of downvotes, but I just can't find anything. I don't know if my problem is specific to my situation or there is a general-purpose solution.

**Basic Outline**

I'm setting up a payment process using Wechat QR codes on my website. The user scans the QR code and completes payment via Wechat Pay on their phone.

This means the user physically completes the process on a different platform, completely away from the website.

After completing the payment, the wechat app sends data to the given callback URL (e.g. `www.mywebsite.com/Finance/PaymentFinished`), where details can be taken from the request headers in the callback.

Via this callback, the server can be updated correctly, thus the payment process is completed and marked on the database.

**Problem**

My question is, how can I tell the website to keep a connection open and listen for that payment update?

**Solution**

Is there a specific way to do this, or should I just write some Javascript that repetitively calls the server (via something like `www.mywebsite/com/Finance/CheckPaymentComplete?userID=1&productID=123`) until it sees a change, and times out if it has to wait too long?

Thanks.

Comment: @MatrixTai Exactly what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a few choices, thanks to @MatrixTai for the suggestion: [Send data to front end when back end updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664262/send-data-to-front-end-when-back-end-updates)

I'll be going with 'long polling', via Javascript's `setTimeout` since this is easiest to get rolling with. This is pretty much what I was originally intending to do anyway.

Thanks!