# Building a Chat application using Server sent Event and node.js

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, server-sent-events

I am new to node.js and SSE.
I want to create a chat application using SSE and node.js.
can any one guide which is better SSE or websocket?
Is there any polyfill for IE using js not php for IE7+

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If the client will never make requests to the server and the server will be doing all the pushing, then you should use server-sent events.

However, for a chat application, because clients need to constantly send requests to the server, the WebSocket API is the natural choice.

The "polyfills" for the WebSocket API are other technologies that mimic a socket connection in a much less efficient manner, like, for example, Ajax long polling.

WebSocket libraries like Socket.IO are designed to use the WebSocket API when available and fall back to other technologies like Ajax long polling when the WebSocket API is not available.

Certain server side languages also handle resources differently.  For example, PHP will require 1 process per socket connection, which can fill a thread limit quickly, whereas NodeJS (IIRC) can loop through the connections and handle them all on 1 thread. So how the language handles resources given your chosen solution should be considered as well.

Comment: Socket.io - too many not well written js code, a lot of issues and simulating of "websockets" with "long polling" - is just a "hack"

Comment: You can use AJAX to post messages to the server, so Web Sockets are not necessary. OTOH SSE provides automatic reconnection, is compatible with HTTP proxies, and can be polyfilled with Comet without special server-side library.

Answer (score 2):

First of all think about compatibility.

**SSE:** http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource

IE: no support

Firefox: Version 6+

Opera: Version 11+

Chrome: Unknown version +

Safari: Version 5.1+

**WebSocket: (protocol 13)** http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

IE: Version 10+

Firefox: Version 11+

Opera: Version 12.1+

Chrome: Version 16+

Safari: Version 6+

I know a lot of modules that works with WebSockets (including one made by me [simpleS](https://github.com/micnic/simpleS/), I made a simple demo chat to show how should the connections be organized in channels, give it a try), and a bit lesser those which works with SSE, I guess that the last ones are less tested and you cannot rely to much on them in comparison with modules that works with WebSockets.

You can find mode information about the WebSockets and SSE here: [WebSockets vs. Server-Sent events/EventSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource)

Comment: does you chat support autoreconnection and detection of disconnects?

Comment: @4esn0k, yes, but it is still very simple, and the API I made, is improving with each new release. Also, I will try to add some new features to the chat, to make the module more popular.

Answer (score 1):

there is a polyfill - https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource (IE8+)
and example of chat - https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/blob/master/tests/server.js