# java script server async events

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, mysql, server-sent-events

I have a web server which I want to send data to the client when the server detects a change in the data base. I want the client to receive the data without polling.

What is the best way to achieve this?

(I read a bit about SSE - server sent events, but not sure this is the way to go)

Thanks

Comment: To detect change in database, there has to be a polling routine.

Comment: database change is in the server, i want to avoid polling the server by the client

Comment: you have mentioned only javascript and jquery, can you please tell us what database you are using and what's your front-end?

Comment: i'm using python bottle as the web framework and have a mysql db on the server side.

Comment: I advice you to include python and mysql tags to your question to get proper replies. Sorry, I cannot guide you much with this question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Server-Sent Events is appropriate technology for listening to changes on the server.

If you're only listening, then SSE is better (faster, lightweight, HTTP-compatible) than a 2-way WebSocket.

Answer (score 0):

If polling is not an option, you can think about the better technique, WebSockets, if your server supports it (and your target browser!).
One way or another, you need a connection opened by the client to the server, though.

Comment: Why is WebSockets better than SSE ?

Comment: I said it's better than traditional polling techniques (IMHO), not than SSE. Both WS and SSE are good at what they do, read more there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource

Answer (score 0):

The answer would vary depending on the freedom you have with client-side Javascript.

If your app gives you complete freedom, you could even set up your client to be a JMS listener and communicate JMS messages from client to server. For ex, you can use [Apache Ajax](http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html).

Another option is to set up your web client to be redis client using, for ex, [Webdis](http://webd.is/)

As you have mentioned, Server-sent-events is an option too, so is WebSockets.
You need to choose based on your constraints.