# How eventSource works with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, websocket

I was reading one of new things in HTML5 [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp).

There are samples with PHP and ASP, how this works with Rails, actually, how this works at all?

Where client that receives data is being specified?

Is this an alternative to WebSockets?

Comment: Take a look at [WebSockets vs. Server-Sent events/EventSource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource)