# Using an HTTP connection as a simple duplex socket in Node

Tags: node.js, http, httprequest

Say we're on a network where only HTTP is allowed, what's the simplest way to use the `http` module as `net` module (TCP) socket/stream? Between two Node servers, I'd like is to be able to send data using `write()` and receive this data with `on('data',...)` at the other end continuously. Currently, I can write once to each end then subsequent writes don't seem to send.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP in its very nature is uni-directional. The best you can get would be two uni-directional channels, without realtime communication.

You can use Server-Sent events([EventSource](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)), which is a part of HTML5 standard. It uses HTTP to transport messages. You should also look at [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) which are similar to tcp sockets. They offer full-duplex realtime communication. They use a different websocket protocol, but can use same ports as http. If websocket is not blocked, you should use it.

Here is a comparison between the two : [WebSockets vs. Server-Sent events/EventSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource)

Comment: This is in the context of two Node applications, not the browser. I've got [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) (RPC) working over HTTP, though I'm just lacking understanding of how it works exactly, hence I'm looking for a barebones example. Not the answer I'm looking for though thanks for response. Will read through the dnode source for answers...

Comment: @jpillora Please update you are working between two node apps in the question.

Comment: sorry about that, fixed