# Rails - how to force refresh page upon item added

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making a simple rails (3.2.11) demo that only i will be accessing. I have the following:

1) a Rails scaffold named Food

2) an android device that can call in to a custom route/controller that will then create a new Food. (`Food.create...`).

So, on my computer's browser, I load up `http://myapp.com`, which is hosting the rails app. Immediately, it loads up all foods because it's rendering `foods#index`. However, the moment i create a new `Food` by calling in from my android device, the browser page (on my computer) is still showing the old list of foods, even though the database knows there's a new food. (because at this point i still haven't refreshed the page)

How do i add a "listener/observer" to refresh the page automatically, when the database changes for the `Food` table? is this possible?

i'm NOT looking for `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` as I would like to leave my computer's browser on for the entire 30 min demo.

=================

also, i haven't used rails in over 3 years, so if you are kind enough to answer, please explain it so that a beginner would understand? (explicit details are preferred)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) or [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/WebSockets) for realtime development . There are also other alternatives like long polling. However, if you are adding a new food from the same page, you could easily catch that event and refresh the data.

Comment: would you be willing to explain with a little bit more detail? more specifically, how i can do it with rails or js?

Comment: @DavidT. There are plenty of examples on the web already. Have a look at https://github.com/DanKnox/websocket-rails perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html). There's an excellent [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) about it that goes into detail about how exactly to get it set up.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, a common option would be to use *[Juggernaut](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut)* to push data from servers to clients. It was used even before websockets became widely used, but it has been recently deprecated in favor of *HTML5 Server-Sent-Events* (SSE). To use SSE, you would apply a client side listener like so:

```
var source = new EventSource('/stream');
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log('Received a message:', e.data);

  //fetch new data with AJAX, or reload
  location.reload();
});
```

Server side, there are many ways to send events. Using [Cramp](http://cramp.in/), sending an event is done like so (taken from documentation):

```
class TimeAction < Cramp::Action
  self.transport = :sse
  #set the transport to Server-Sent Event

  on_start :send_latest_time
  periodic_timer :send_latest_time, :every => 2

  def send_latest_time
    data = {'time' => Time.now.to_i}.to_json
    render data
  end
end
```

If you're using Sinatra, your code would look like this:

```
get '/stream', :provides => 'text/event-stream' do
  stream :keep_open do |out|
    connections << out
    out.callback { connections.delete(out) }
  end
end
```

Server sent events are supported in mostly any browser, except for Internet Explorer and Opera Mini, but there are a few fallbacks/polyfill libraries such as the one [here](https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js) or [here](https://github.com/rwaldron/jquery.eventsource) (jQuery solution). Unlike websockets, they still use the HTTP protocol, but keep in mind that they are one-way, while websockets can be used for multidirectional communication. If you're curious about the differences between SSE and websockets, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource).