# Is Modernizr really needed if you're not using the feature detection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

I keep jumping into projects where Modernizr is located in the head, but it isn't being used (at least for feature detection). Now, I love Modernizr, I use it frequently for feature detection and fallbacks on projects that require it; however, the last three projects I've come into it's been sitting in the head without any of the feature detection classes being called. These projects are using vanilla javascript <s>and/or do not require jQuery polyfills at all.</s> <sup>1</sup> That being said... if you're not using the feature detection <s>and really don't need to load a jQuery library</s> <sup>2</sup>, is Modernizr really doing anything aside from making an addition HTTP request and resource to load?

I'm not strong enough with jQuery/javascript to understand if it's affecting anything else under the hood.

---

**Edit**

<sup>1</sup> & <sup>2</sup> — Modernizr is javascript and doesn't require the jQuery library (which makes me wonder why the jQuery library is being loaded also, at least in these cases).

*Modernizr.min* with only `#-shiv-cssclasses-load` is 7.57 KB whereas *html5shiv.min* is only 3 KB.

Comment: It also has an HTML5Shim for IE<9

Comment: It migth influence global variables, but I do not know Modernizr internally, I guess they are not setting any, but somebody else has to come. ;)

Comment: What does Modernizr have to do with jQuery? I think there is absolutely no relation in any direction.

Comment: Ok, from what @Royinamir says, they do set them...

Comment: @hgoebl I wasn't certain if Modernizr required the jQuery library (like I said, not a js dev by any standard).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Generally speaking, Modernizr does three things.

1. It adds classes indicating feature support, allowing you to apply different styling to elements depending on what features they support.
2. It allows you to run feature detection to decide whether to run a script/run a polyfill or not.
3. It injects html5shiv, which allows old browsers to understand HTML5 elements.

If you don't use any of these features, then there's no point in including Modernizr at all. If you only use it for the [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) then you could probably just include that instead to save a few bytes, although I doubt there's a relevant size difference at all.

That said, you should never include feature detects in a modernizr build that you don't use. That's nothing but a waste.

Answer (score 12):

Modernizr also include shims which save you from defining them yourself  or including another library.

The main goal of Modernizr is to use detection via classes. so you can do something like this:

Example, where you want to change behaviour depending on whether the client support flash:

```
.flash #flashdiv
{
  display:block;
}   

.no-flash #flashdiv
{
  display:none;
}
```

It really helps you to dynamically deal with the abilities different client browsers.

Also, you can use Modernizr to detect HTML5 features and provide fallbacks (polyfills).

Eg:

```
<script>
  if (Modernizr.canvas) {
    alert("This browser supports HTML5 canvas!"); //you can load js here. or use yepnope)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Just came along this feature, which is added in Modernizr: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5326159/2672018 SSE-Polyfill.