# WebSocket and SSE working difference in html5

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I want some clarification on the WebSocket and SSE. In websocket two way communication possible, but in SSE one way.In both connection is persistent, then why is difference ? 
Is there is difference in the number of port opened with websocket and SSE from client side ?.

Comment: And what is SSE? Not the RAM instruction set I hope...

Comment: BTW you need only one port for websockets. Sockets are by definition bidirectionnal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource

Comment: @FlorianMargaine SSE is Server Sent Event.  It's a simple one way (server to client) event path.  Think stock ticker.