# Play Framework 2.x: How to update a displayed view from server side?

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0, server-sent-events

I have some problems with the play! framework. 
The framework is new for me and my first and only practise with it, is this tutorial [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList).

I have a *view* which lists up some data. A *Controller* which have one method to show the *view* and another method which can receive some data with *JSON*. Now i would like to update the *view* when new data(*JSON*) is received.

I found out, that i can use either a *comet socket*, a *websocket* or *server-sent events* to implement this.
(*A permanent AJAX-polling ist not a option for me to do it.*)

What is the best way to do this?

I tried to solve it with *websockets*, but it does not work as i want...

Here is my code:

```
public class MyController extends Controller{   
    public static Result showMyView() {
        return ok(views.html.showMyView.render(Data.all()));
    }

    @BodyParser.Of(play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class)
    public static Result jsonReceiver() {
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        String rcvData = json.findPath("someData").textValue();

        if(rcvData != null) {
            /*FLAG*/
            //SEND SOME DATA OVER THE WEBSOCKET FROM HERE?! ..To update the view
            //something like: out.write("Now from here!");
            return ok();
        } else {
            return badRequest();
        }
    }

    public static WebSocket<String> websocket() {
        return new WebSocket<String>() {

            public void onReady(WebSocket.In<String> in, WebSocket.Out<String> out) {
                out.write("Hello!");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Is there any way to send messages or other data over the socket from the position `/*FLAG*/` in the code above?

My view looks like this:

```
@(dataContent: List[Data])
@main(title = "MyViews Observation Page") {
    @*
    SOME HTML CODE ...
    *@

<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host + "/path/to/my/websocket")

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        alert("Received: " + event.data); // only for testing... will be replaced later
    }
</script>
}
```

Can anybody help me here? I don't know how to update the view, when new data is received.

I would be very grateful if you could show it on the basis of my example code above.
if it is easier to make it in a different way(comet or server-sent events), I am also very grateful for examples.

In my previous investigation i have found a few examples for comet and server-sent events but they were only in scala and i haven't understood them.

I'm using play framework 2.2.2 with java.

Comment: I worked with websockets, it's complicated for some reasons (compatibility with proxys, connexion closing unexpectedly). You can still do it if you have a compatible proxy and if you ping the connexion every x seconds, to recover if fail.

Comment: Ok. I've never before worked with websockets. Can you recommend a solution approach for my problem? I'm very flexible in the way to do this. At the end i mainly need a 'observation page' which is updated after the JSON data is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each client will generate a `WebSocket.Out` on your server.

Store them in a List, and then call `WebSocket.Out.write(objectNode)`

```
public class MyController extends Controller{   
    //1. you store your client channels here
    private static ArrayList<WebSocket.Out> channels=new ArrayList<>();

    public static Result showMyView() {
        return ok(views.html.showMyView.render(Data.all()));
    }

    @BodyParser.Of(play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class)
    public static Result jsonReceiver() {
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        String rcvData = json.findPath("someData").textValue();

        if(rcvData != null) {
           //3. you can write in your channels :)
           for(WebSocket.Out channel : channels){
               channel.write("blah");
           }

            return ok();
        } else {
             return badRequest();
        }
    }

    public static WebSocket<String> websocket() {
        return new WebSocket<String>() {

            public void onReady(WebSocket.In<String> in, WebSocket.Out<String> out) {
                  //2. each time a client connects, you save a reference to its channel
                  channels.add(out);
            }
        };
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you, that helped me. In your post above... you have wrote that the connection can be closed unexpectedly. I thought, that websockets are a fine solution for a problem like this. Isn't it? Would it be better to use comet or server-side events?

Comment: Yes it would. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource