# Inform ember-data about server changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, websocket, ember-data

I am currently planning a complex application using ruby on rails and ember.js. What I have seen about ember-data so far is that it caches records automatically; `post.comments` will first result in a Ajax-call to fetch all comments for the given post, but if the user visits the same route the next time, it will just fetch the records from the store-cache.

The problem is: What if another user added a comment to this post? How to tell ember it has to reload its cache because something changed?

I already thought about a solution using websockets to tell clients which stuff to reload - but I don't think this is best-practice. And in addition, I can't imagine this isn't a common problem, so I am wondering what other developers are doing to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to implement model updating in (experimental) chat application. I have used [SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource): `ActionController::Live` on server side (Ruby on Rails) and `EventSource` on client side.

Simplified code:

```
App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    if (! this.eventSource) {
      this.eventSource = new EventSource('/messages/events');

      var self = this;
      this.eventSource.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(e.data);
        if (data.id != self.controllerFor('messages').get('savedId')) {
          self.store.createRecord('message', data);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    create: function() {
      var data = this.getProperties('body');
      var message = this.store.createRecord('message', data);
      var self = this;
      message.save().then(function (response) {
        self.set('savedId', response.id);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The logic is simple: I'm getting each new record from EventSource. Then, if record was created by another client, the application detects it and new record being added to store using `ember-data`'s `createRecord`. Suppose this logic may have some caveats, but at least it serves well as 'proof of concept'. Chat is working.

Full sources available here: https://github.com/denispeplin/ember-chat/

I have something to say about reloading: you probably don't want to perform full reloading, it's resource-consuming operation. Still, your client side needs some way to know about new records. So, getting new records one-by-one via SSE is probably the best option.

Comment: getting resources one-by-one is not only time consuming, but adds a ton of extra overhead. Not just locally on the client, but uses a bunch of extra resourses on the server-side as well. Keeping track of an `updated_at` field (which rails will manage automatically) allows the app to fetch only newly-modified records and will allow the cache to do what it is meant for old records

Comment: The problem of this is that my complex web application is kind of a game and therefore based on very many user interactions. Keeping track of what exactly I have to reload when one specific action is happening is already a huge overhead in the backend and will occur many, many errors, I guess.

Comment: Well, you can use Pusher or PubNub services to broadcast messages, or install some SSE proxy on your server. Rails will only broadcast once, but every client will receive update.

Comment: Do you find that this solution works equally well when propgating updates to the data via SSEs? With your chat that would amount to someone editing a previous comment I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get rid of caching you can force a [reload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload) every time user navigates to comments `route`. But this largely depends on what you are trying to acheieve, I hope `comments` is just an example.

If you want your `ui` to get updated automagically with changes in server, you need some communication with server, some polling mechanism like `websocket` or polling from a `webworker`. Then you may `reload` the list of changed records sent from server. You are probably on the right track with this.

You can as well take a look at the [orbitjs](https://github.com/orbitjs/orbit.js/tree/master) standalone library that integrates well with Ember. This is more useful if you require local storage as well and got to manage the multiple data sources.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I will do this; disabling embers cache / changing embers behaviour to reload all stuff which is only displayed on a single page and using a websocket automatic update for things which are always displayed, as in the ui.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a common problem with any web application, no matter what framework you are using.  From my point of view, there are two main options.  One:  You have a service that polls the server to check to see if there are any changes that would require you to reload some of your models, have that service return those model IDs and refresh them.  The other option is as you suggested, using a websocket and pushing notifications of model changes/new models themselves.

I would opt to actually just send the comment model itself, and push it into the Ember store and the associated post object.  This would reduce the need to hit the server with a hard refresh of your model.  I am currently using this method with my Ember app, where there is an object that contains overview data based on all the models in my app, and when a change is made in the backend, my websocket server pushes the new overview data to me application.

UPDATE:: I meant for this to be a comment, not an answer, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue with mobile app development. While websockets seemed like the first answer, I was worried about scalability issues with limited server resources. I decided to stick with the Ajax call to fetch newly modified records. This way server resources are only used if the user is active. However, as others pointed out, returning all comments every single time you need data makes your cacheing useless and is slow. I suggest updating your rails server to accept an optional timestamp. If the timestamp is not supplied, then every comment is retrieved. If a timestamp is supplied, then only return comments where the `updated_at` column is `>=` the supplied timestamp. This way, if no comments were added or modified since your last call, then you quickly get back an empty list and can move on. If results are returned, you can then merge them with your existing list and show the updated comments.

**Example of fetching newly created or modified comments**

```
if params.has_key?(:updated_since)
  comments = Post.find(params[:id]).comments.where("updated_at >= ?", params[:updated_since])
else
  comments = Post.find(params[:id]).comments
end
```

Comment: Ember will not even make a request if comments have already been loaded. Changing this behaviour in ember makes it nearly useless, I guess.