# Persisting server-side data across an array of clients

Tags: php, database, web-services

I have a PHP website and a SQL database. Users will be able to update this data with a mobile phone. I would like all users to receive these updates. How would I do this?

I could simply use ajax and a timer to have each client request updates at a given interval.

Is there a way to set a callback of sorts so that a service on the server calls a list of method instances? This would prevent unnecessary requests and transfer of data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a third-party solution like the one @Alexandre Martin suggested, you could use Server Sent Events. The flow is as follows:

1. Each user subscribes to a channel (think of it as registering an event listener on a connection). On the server side, a script is running continuously to track for changes
2. A user posts an update to the server.
3. The script notices the update and issues an event
4. All clients who subscribed to the channel receive the event, read its `data` property and update their local models.

See [this introduction](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/), with sample PHP implementation.

You could also use Web Sockets. Here is a [comparison of the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource). Before implementing either, consider [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/eventsource).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase to create an online database and to send upload and download messages from and to clients as soon as an internet connection is detected (also called *Cloud messaging*)

SQLite manages offline operations directly on the device and is synchronized with Firebase automatically.

Look at the *Get started* page and you will find web, iOS and Android tutorials. http://firebase.google.com