# How to receive server side events similar to Facebook notifications

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, websocket, server-sent-events

I am wondering on how to implement user notifications just like facebook does on its site. At the moment I am calling a php script using angular timer which tells me if any notification is available in the database. Is there any technique that I can use to push notifications to angular code?

Comment: It sounds like you have implemented polling. You can look into sockets if you want real-time communication from server to web browser.

Comment: There are two browser APIs that can receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server: [EventSource Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) and [WebSockets Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: See [WebSockets vs. Server-Sent events/EventSource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource).