# Streaming Server-Sent Events (SSE) in F#

Tags: f#, server-sent-events, .net-4.8

What is a lightweight way to stream "server-sent events (SSE) style" events to the front-end in F#, using the System.Net.Http library? I understand the Event stream format (e.g. [this PHP example code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#sending_events_from_the_server)), but I am seeking some guidance to implement the streaming part in a server-side F# application (I'm on .Net Framework 4.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following minimalistic, rudimentary code works (OS: Windows10, Browser: Google Chrome 92.0.4515, .Net Framework 4.8) :

F# client-side code:

```
module SSE0 =
    open System
    open System.IO
    open System.Net

let pipeUTF8 (data: string) (sink: Stream) : Async<unit> = async {
    let bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes data
    use src = new MemoryStream(bytes)
    do! src.CopyToAsync(sink) |> Async.AwaitTask }

let private (=>=) data sink = pipeUTF8 data sink

type Msg = { id: string; event: string; data: string } with
    member this.send (sink: Stream) : Async<unit> = async { 
        do! (sprintf "id:%s\n" this.id) =>= sink
        do! (sprintf "event:%s\n" this.event) =>= sink
        do! (sprintf "data:%s\n\n" this.data) =>= sink // Only works for single-line data payloads (won't work if eol included)
        do! " \n" =>= sink
        do! Async.Sleep 1000 // only for this basic example
        Console.WriteLine(sprintf "id: %s, event: %s, data: %s" this.id this.event this.data)
        do! sink.FlushAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask}

let sse_count (ctx : HttpListenerContext) : Async<unit> =
    let output  = ctx.Response.OutputStream
    let message (i: int) : Msg = { id = sprintf "id#%02d" i; event = "message"; data = sprintf "data#%02d" i }
    let msgs = seq { for i in 0 .. 59 -> let msg = message i in async { do! msg.send output } }
    msgs |> Async.Sequential |> Async.Ignore

let startServer (url: string) (handler: HttpListenerContext -> Async<unit>) (cts: Threading.CancellationTokenSource) : Threading.CancellationTokenSource =
    let task = async {
        use listener = new HttpListener()
        listener.Prefixes.Add(url)
        listener.Start()
        while true do
            let! context = listener.GetContextAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            let resp = context.Response
            [ ("Content-Type", "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8") 
            ; ("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
            ; ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") ] // or Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
            |> List.iter(fun (k, v) -> resp.AddHeader(k, v))
            Async.Start (handler context, cts.Token)
        }
    Async.Start (task, cts.Token)
    cts

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let cts' = defaultArg None <| new Threading.CancellationTokenSource()

    Console.WriteLine("Press return to start.")
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore

    Console.WriteLine("Running...")
    let cts = startServer "http://localhost:8080/events/" sse_count cts'
    
    Console.WriteLine("Press return to exit.")
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    cts.Cancel()
    0
```

html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>SSE test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="btn">Close the connection</button>
        <ul id="msglist"></ul>

        <script>
            var es = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080/events/");
            
            es.onopen = function() {
                console.log("Connection to server opened.");
            };
            
            var msgList = document.getElementById("msglist");
            es.onmessage = function(e) {
                console.log("type: " + e.type +  ", id: " + e.lastEventId + ", data: " + e.data);
                
                var newElement = document.createElement("li");
                newElement.textContent = "type: " + e.type +  ", id: " + e.lastEventId + ", data: " + e.data;
                msgList.appendChild(newElement);
            };

            var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
            btn.onclick = function() {
                console.log("Connection closed");
                es.close();
            }
            
            es.onerror = function(e) {
                console.log("Error found.");
            };
        </script>
    </body>
```

The following resources were useful to get this done :

https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/tree/master/server-sent-events

https://github.com/haf/FSharp.EventSource

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Suave](https://suave.io/).  The below example sends a message every second (using SSE)  I haven't tried it in .net 47 ( I tried in .net 5 in Mac) but it should work.

```
open Suave
open Suave.Sockets
open Suave.Sockets.Control
open Suave.EventSource
open Suave.Operators
open Suave.Filters

let write i out =
    socket {
      let msg = { id = string i; data = string i; ``type`` = None }
      do! msg |> send out
      return! SocketOp.ofAsync (Async.Sleep 1000)
    }
    
    
let app =
  choose [
          GET  >=> request (fun _ -> 
            handShake (fun out ->
              socket {
                let actions  = 
                    Seq.initInfinite (fun n -> n + 1)
                    |> Seq.map (fun i -> write i out)

                for a in actions do
                    do! a
                   
                return out
              }))
    
    
[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
     startWebServer defaultConfig app
     0
```

Comment: Thanks. I can only use System.Net and the like, but I'll see how I can adapt your Suave-based solution with the tools I can use.

Comment: @Janthelme that's a big limitation. Good luck.  Are you sure you can't use any nuget packages at all?

Comment: @Janthelme also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851970/implement-sending-server-sent-events-in-c-sharp-no-asp-net-mvc.  This has some boilerplate code in C#

Comment: Yes, unfortunately no choice, suave would have been nice. Thanks for your link.