# React - Java Backend - Sync New Data

Tags: java, database, reactjs, synchronization

I'm having a small problem with a personal project, I'm trying to create an auction site in React - it's an amazing learning experience - with a Java backend.

One trouble I've stumbled upon is how to "sync" data effectively, when new data is inserted into the database from a different user, such as if a user would bid on an item, how would other users update their data?

The only way I can see it happening is with a push model, or constantly polling for data from the server. Both seem pretty out of reach, to be honest, although the push-model seems the more likely of the two.

I could somehow set up an observer pattern with users "registered" when viewing an item, although if there is a better method, I would love to hear it.

I already tried searching for answers, but either none exist (I doubt it), or I'm simply terrible at using Google and don't know the keywords to search for to get the specific results I need. (Likely)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keyword: Websockets

Comment: I need to keep the websocket open for the full duration of their "viewing" of the item, though, correct? In which case it becomes a push-model for data flow, which - from my rather poor explanation - I was trying to avoid, if there was some other magical way of syncing data.

Comment: Try looking at Server-Sent-Events then maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource

Comment: That looks very promising, and somewhat exactly what I was thinking/need.
Much appreciated!

Comment: Filed an answer, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a kind of server push technology. Try researching more into `Websockets` or `Server-Sent-Events`.

A start could be: [WebSockets vs. Server-Sent events/EventSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource)