# What are some good use cases for Server Sent Events

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

I discovered SSE (Server Sent Events) pretty late, but I can't seem to figure out some use cases for it, so that it would be more efficient than using `setInterval()` and `ajax`.

I guess, if we'd have to update the data multiple times per second then having one single connection created would produce less overhead. But, except this case, when would one really choose SSE?

I was thinking of this scenario:

> A new user comment from the website is added in the database
>
> Server periodically queries DB for changes. If it finds new comment, send notification to client with SSE

Also, this SSE question came into my mind after having to do a simple "live" website change (when someone posts a comment, notify everybody who is on the site). Is there really another way of doing this without periodically querying the database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nowadays web technologies are used to implmement all sort of applications, including those which need to fetch constant **updates** from the server.

As an example, imagine to have a **graph** in your web page which displays **real time data**. Your page must refresh the graph any time there is new data to display.

Before *Server Sent Events* the only way to obtain new data from the server was to perform a new request every time.

## Polling

As you pointed out in the question, one way to look for updates is to use `setInterval()` and an `ajax` request. With this technique, our client will perform a request once every X seconds, no matter if there is new data or not. This technique is known as **polling**.

## Events

Server Sent Events on the contrary are **asynchronous**. The server itself will notify to the client when there is new data available.

In the scenario of your example, you would implement SSE such in a way that the server sends an event immediately after adding the new comment, and not by polling the DB.

## Comparison

Now the question may be when is it advisable to use polling vs SSE. Aside from compatibility issues (**not all browsers support SSE**, although there are some polyfills which essentially emulate SSE via polling), you should focus on the **frequency and regularity** of the updates.

If you are uncertain about the frequency of the updates (how often new data *should* be available), SSE may be the solution because they avoid all the extra requests that polling would perform.

However, it is wrong to say in general that SSE produce less overhead than polling. That is because **SSE requires an open TCP** connection to work. This essentially means that some resources on the server (e.g. a worker and a network socket) are allocated to one client until the connection is over. With polling instead, after the request is answered the connection may be reset.

Therefore, I would **not** recommend to use SSE if the average number of connected clients is high, because this could create some overhead on the server.

In general, I advice to use SSE only if your application requires real time updates. As real life example, I developed a **data acquisition** software in the past and had to provide a web interface for it. In this case, a lot of graphs were updated every time a new data point was collected. That was a **good fit** for SSE because the number of connected clients was low (essentially, only one), the user interface should update in real-time, and the server was not flooded with requests as it would be with polling.

Many applications do not require real time updates, and thus it is perfectly acceptable to display the updates with some delay. In this case, polling with a long interval may be viable.

Comment: So for SSE it means I need to insert it in the `insertComment()` script of the server, right?
Also, can you shortly talk also about `WebSockets` in your comparison above? The overhead thing, tcp, real time, many users etc. Thanks

Comment: Yes, pretty much. As for your question about WebSockets, I would recommend to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource) here on SO.