# Getting notifications immediately after adding a row to the table in a database

Tags: database, spring, angular, push-notification, notifications

I'm creating a web application these days.

Backend portion is implemented in Spring Boot (inter alia MVC and Data), but frontend portion is implemented in Angular.

I would like to create push notifications [like that](https://dzone.com/articles/browser-push-notification-in-angular-5) which would be displayed **in real time** after adding a row to the table in the database (from a level of frontend).

For example:

Step 1. User adds one element to the table (send `POST` request)

Step 2. Other users get the push notification with inforamtion that the element was added. (If the response staus is `CREATED`)

I have created classes (controller, model, view) but this data is displayed on the basis of `GET` request so far. Typically... because if I don't refresh the page, I don't see any changes.

What do you think - what technologies should I use to achieve above result? Or maybe there's some tutorials with implementation similar problems?

Comment: Notifications from the server to another user are handled with sockets. Find more information here : https://socket.io/

Comment: Thanks for the clue ;)

Comment: Another option would be to use [SSE](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp).You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource) for the difference with  web sockets. Web sockets can be an overkill in some cases.

Comment: @Rohit thank you :) SSEs could be better in my case...