# Push datas from Sql Server to Client Browser

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, apache

I having an external System whitch is writing datas in a Table of my Sql-Server.

This datas should shown realtime (max. delay not more then 1. sec) in the Browser of a connected Client.

I was thinking to use Ajax to do this. So like creating a JS timer whitch runs every second and sending a ajax request to the Server to get the datas of the table. But I thing thats not the best and above all not the performance optimiced way to do this.

Structure:

[image]

There are some better possibilities to do this? 
I think the best way is when the Apache-Webserver noted that there was a change in the table and than push the data to the conneted client!

Greetings

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource help?

Comment: Yes, thanks Nico.  I think this goes in the right direction , but the question for me is still how the Apache server knows when there is a change in the tabel of the sql server and how did he get the datas from the table