# AngularJS communicating with two tab in the same browser

Tags: angularjs

For example, i keep opened two tab in the same browser with the url

like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/#!/crud`

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/#!/crud
```

I want to achieve like if i change anything in one tab, the other tab of the same url should get an alert or automatically refresh the page to be the same as other tab.

how can i archive this?

here you go for my controller of GET method:

```
$scope.getAllContact = function() {
    var data = $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.contacts = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
    });
  };
  $scope.getAllContact();
```

I want to implement like if any change occurs in a tab, the change should reflect to other tab too. i mean, all the tab should be same with same url but so that it doesn't reflect on other urls of tab

Comment: You need to do Real time communication with web sockets but on server side. Like SignalR for .Net. But start from Web Sockets and see how they work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource

Comment: any other way without web socket?

Comment: google push notifications