# is it possible to provide restful service from react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, express, post

i'm working on a web project that should provide restful post service with react framework.

there are a lot of consuming rest service example on internet.

however, i want to provide restful service.

I tried the following,

1- provide service from react framework. i see it is not possible.

2- provide service from express and binding it with react via proxy
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0t42xBIYIs

for this example, get method works but post method does not.

my express server like below.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/api/customers', (req, res) => {

  res.json(req.body);
});


const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

after that, , use proxy and react code like this

```
  componentDidMount()
  {

      fetch('/api/customers')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(customers => this.setState({customers}, () => console.log('Customers fetched...', customers)));
```

at that point i get the below error

```
customers.js:18 GET http://localhost:3000/api/vehicles 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

thank you for all advice.

i'm searching for best practice.

Comment: What is `fetch` inside `fetch`? is it  a typo? and url `lhost:3000` and endpoint `lhost:5000` are different and you may require cors library too. also you should check how to use fetch for post req.

Comment: It doesn't work because you're not making a POST request from React or defining a GET for that route in Express.

Comment: fetch inside fetch is typo while pasting to stackoverflow. 5000 is express port. 3000 is react client port. they are bound with proxy.

Comment: i don't want to do post request from react. i want to do it externally like postman.

Comment: ` web project that should provide restful post service with react framework` that is not react is built for. what is your requirement over this?

Comment: yeah i see that for first try. i m searching for the best practice. should i use express server for providing reset service or what ever else. final aim is that there is a list (customers ) contuniously changing via post request. i should show on reactjs.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a React application build are script bundles and html files (also can include source maps for debugging) commonly referred to as build artifacts.

**The best practice is simple:**
 When Express is involved the React app should download the build artifacts and API responses from Express (commonly called backend in this scenario).

**What happens when this is not followed:**
1. React frontend server (typically `webpack-dev-server`) is used in production. This is not a good idea, `webpack-dev-server`is meant to be used in development only.
2. Browser detects that JS code from the bundles downloaded from one server (frontend) attempts to call another server (backend) and triggers a security violation which is meant to improve security. People then use CORS HTTP headers (sent by backend) to make the backend tell browsers: "Don't worry about security and don't trigger security violations, I (the backend) has been hardened to such an extent that I don't care that some code downloaded not from me tries to access me". The browser complies and this results in security needlessly watered down.

**When to proxy:**
In development only. The `webpack-dev-server` is excellent for development with its support for Live Reloading, HMR etc. To keep those advantages the backend (Express) can and should serve as a reverse proxy for the frontend. E.g. when Express receives a request for a build artifact, it should download it from the frontend first and then use it to send the response back. This ensures CORS issues do not arise.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues stand out

*Post vs Get*

You're serving your api from a post endpoint. Change it to `get`.

```
app.get('/api/customers', (req, res) => {res.json(vehicleList);});
```

*fetch*

In the UI, it shows you are fetching from *localhost:3000* when you should be fetching from *localhost:5000*. I assume your proxy is rerouting *3000* -> *5000* so hopefully this isn't an issue. I would however doublecheck and try hitting the localhost:3000/api/customers url (copy and paste that into the url bar) and see if you see your json.

*Also*

It is certainly possible to have express serve the static react bundle from a the same base url as your api.
**e.g.**

```
app.use('/', express.static('public'));
app.post('/api/customers', (req, res) => {
  res.json(vehicleList);
});
```

Comment: i m sorry for vehicleList tag. it should be  "req.body". if i change it to get, i cannot get new customers list via postman.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you didn't focus that both are running on two different **ports**
like your server is running on `Port:5000` and react project `port:3000` so just add
`"proxy":http://localhost:5000`

```
//server.js  (node file)***

app.get('/api/customers', (req, res) => {
  const customers = [
    {id: 1, Name: 'Rohan', email: 'r@gmail.com'},
    {id: 2, Name: 'Rohan', email: 'r@gmail.com'}
  ];

  res.json(customers);
});

const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`)

// React Script***

class Customers extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      customers: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/customers')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(customers => this.setState({customers}, () => console.log('Customers fetched...', customers)));
  }
```

Comment: i said that get method works. problem is post method. i have dynamically changing customers array. some other project will post a customers list to my project.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no method for pushing data from server to client in a convensional way.

there is a good subject to push data from server to client. you may want to see that.

[WebSocket vs ServerSentEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource)