# Performance difference between websocket and server sent events (SSE) for chat room for 10,000 users?

Tags: websocket, server-sent-events

SSE is based on HTTP protocol, and `ws` requires one time HTTP upgrade.

For a small user base, I understand, WebSocket is way too good over SSE.

I am worried about how much difference will it be for 10,000 user chat system. Here the major concern is:

For **WebSocket**, I will have to **run a loop for 10,000 connections** to emit a message every time a new message is received.

For **SSE**, there is **no loop**, but a single server-sent event that will stream data to 10,000 users.

To me, Looking on paper it looks like SSE is best for such a large number, especially when numbers of connected clients will keep increasing to 20,000, 100,000. There is no 10,000 value loop running for every new message.

Is it practically true as well? I tried searching quite some performance benchmark for WebSocket vs SSE but can't find any.

Please confirm, if **SSE will have better performance and low server resource utilization over WebSocket** for emitting / streaming messages to such a large no. of users?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebSockets vs. Server-Sent events/EventSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource)

Comment: @ScottStensland - I already read the information shared in your URL and it has the only definition, meaning, and advantages one over other. I am already aware of the information. But my concern here is the "Performance Gap" for one over other on the server especially for large numbers where WebSocket starts falling slowly with growing numbers. For example: "10K users chat room group" <- here on WebSocket for every message emit a loop will run for 10K connection, but on SSE, there is no loop, it's just a stream to throw to subscribers. Would love response from someone who has done this before!

Comment: @JohnCargo, I'm exploring SSE and Websocket. Did you find the answer? It would be helpful for the community if you could share it with us.

Comment: @SanjaySharma - This can be helpful ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/5326159/2819754

Comment: Maybe worth a read as well, especially regarding performance: https://www.timeplus.com/post/websocket-vs-sse TLDR: performance is very similar, bottleneck is client CPU (especially in chrome as one process handles all the network traffic), WS seems to use slightly less CPU when pushing the limits, in real world scenarios SSE seems to have a slight edge in terms of CPU usage

Answer (score 2):

It depends how much those users talk, and what protocol you use to make them talk, when choosing SSE.

WebSockets is for two-way communication, Server Sent Events is one-way (you use other communication to talk to the server).

Both protocols actually consume a "socket" on the server, and both usually even use the same code to emit data on the socket (Node.js uses the same C code).

- SSE opens a "text/event-stream" connection without a handshake.
- WebSocket opens an "upgraded" connection with a handshake (1 more round trip to make the connection for two-way talking).

SSE has no send capability. Since almost all attacks come from errors in implementation, SSE was created to allow people to make "more secure" (in that they are simpler, and there is less that can possibly go wrong) systems if you only want to send data to clients. Other than that, they are pretty much the same; extremely streamlined, and no bandwidth overhead.

***Generally, choose SSE if you don't need to hear from the client very often, and choose WebSockets if you do.***

Benchmarks for SSE vs WebSockets are going to be mostly misguided or filled with implementation noise, because there is no difference if you use them for the same thing (one-way communication) because their bandwidth and compute is the same (zero overhead) and a lot of difference if you implement them poorly (you might send things way more than you need to).

If you're using chat where two-way communication is high, SSE is going to be likely slower than WebSockets, but only because you need to implement something to send messages with SSE because it's one-way only, and most people use regular HTTPS, which can include 700+ bytes of additional header info each time you do. It is not the fault of SSE.

SSE is not any faster than WebSockets; both protocols are literally identical when traveling over the network (i.e., there is no additional bytes of traffic in their protocols); they use no bandwidth other than what overhead you put in the messages once the connection is established.

Because of this, all of the trade-offs are going to be in your use case and your implementation.

SSE wasn't designed to replace WebSockets, it was designed to offer super-simple one-way communication as an alternative to WebSockets; the intention is only for simpler design if using one-way communication. That's it.

The speed is going to be entirely up to you in how you implement your specific use.

For example, if you hold incomming messages for a second, then broadcast them all once instead of as they arrive, you could possibly get a 10x to 100x compute and bandwidth improvement by trading off sub-second speed, just because you waited a bit to broadcast; but this is an implementation detail that can be done with either protocol.

If you have more than a million users and you need to spread messages to more than a single client, how you agregate messages between servers is going to be your major bottleneck (i.e. do you use an in-memory db shared between clients, do you use redis or a newer faster db like aerospike or dragonfly, do you use MongoDB or PosgreSQL's notification systems, or something like Kafka? All these things are going to matter 100x more than choosing SSE over WebSockets.

In general, you can cram a million users or more into a single server with WebSockets or SSE. You'll run out of bandwidth from your actual messages long before the compute will hit a wall, and since the protocol bandwidth per message isn't an issue (there is none), you don't have to worry about that.

If you're implementing live chat, where 99.9% of people never talk, if you're only broadcasting telemetry where nobody talks, or if you're implementing something like side-channel stream data where nothing is sent by clients, SSE is probably a good choice because of how simple it is to get running, because the slowest server is one it takes you years to implement :)

In the end, SSE has one benefit and one drawback over WebSockets for broadcast scenarios (one-way communication):

1. It's a simpler architecture, so there is less to think about.
2. Unlike WebSocket, SSE currently has no default inspector for browsers, so you have to add a plugin, like https://github.com/maltoze/sse-viewer

Both architectures require a full HTTPS handshake to start the connection.

Answer (score -1):

For broadcasting sse faster because websocket protocol has to decode/encode data. you have to loop both of them. but if you use sse you should send data with post protocol which is slower than websocket.