# Should I minimise the number of subscriptions in my relay application?

Tags: graphql, relay, relaymodern, react-relay, graphql-relay

I am new to using graphql and we have built a backend graphql server using elixir and we are building a frontend app using react and react-relay.

My question is whether it is better to have one large subscription at the root of my query renderer instead of having loads of smaller subscriptions for individual components. I think I would prefer using lots and lots of smaller subscriptions rather than fewer (or even one) very large subscriptions but there are concerns that too many subscriptions will be very heavy. Is this valid?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider here, and really, they all depend on what your definition of "very heavy" is. Note "very heavy" might mean something very different for your Elixir server implementation than it does on the client, so I will attempt to cover some directions you may want to investigate for both here.

- What is your subscription transport? Websockets can be expensive and difficult to scale on both ends at a certain point, but if you can deal with unidirectional data flow (server to client only), SSE (Server-Sent Events) are a great option. [See more on a breakdown between SSE and WS here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5326159/4301222). This is more a comment on your server than on your client.
- From an API design perspective, I'd caution against the few (or one) large subscriptions idea. Why? Inevitably, you are going to be pushing data on the client that it never asked for; this causes unnecessary work for both client and server. Furthermore, an individual component should only be able to subscribe to data screams with data specifically designated for it. If you go the large subscription route, then you'll have to write a good deal of defensive code to filter the event stream, looking for the data you need. That shouldn't be your responsibility to micromanage, not to mention the dirty event stream on your server.

This is not necessarily to lead you down the "small subscription" route either. Ultimately, you might want to look at [this hybrid approach](https://hackernoon.com/the-hybrid-strategy-for-graphql-subscriptions-dd5471c45755) , which articulates my opinions on the matter better than I can myself. TL;DR design the subscriptions API so that you can enjoy the tightly scoped benefits of lots of small subscriptions ("per entity," as the author titles them), but still allow you to share payloads and reuse the same handlers that your mutations do to resolve data.

Plus, if you wanted to use [persisted queries](https://relay.dev/docs/en/persisted-queries) the hybrid approach is going to serve you better.