# Provide live updates from Spring API Restcontroller to browser clients

Tags: java, spring

**Background**:
I have a spring webapp which every 10 seconds polls a RestController API server for various information like employee information and their task information, and a json response object is returned. This employee status and task information is stored in a backend database and served by the rest api calls to the client browsers.

An example call and response is like:

**client javascript**:

```
await getEmployeeInfo();
```

**Returns**:

```
{
    "employees": [{
            "id": "0001",
            "name": "john",
            "status": "online",
            "tasks": ["task1", "task2"]
        },
        {
            "id": "0002",
            "name": "pam",
            "status": "out-to-lunch",
            "tasks": ["task2", "task3"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Once the above response is received by the client browser, it is then parsed and displayed graphically on a webpage.

**What I want to do**:
Instead of polling the server for new information every few seconds, I would rather call the `getEmployeeInfo()` API, receive the information, and have the HTTP connection kept open to receive updates if their are any.

**What I don't want to do**:
Hammer the server by polling every few seconds to receive the latest information from the server, even though there hasn't been any updates since the last poll. I could reduce the polling frequency to reduce server load, but then the *realtimeness* of the information would suffer.

**My Question**:
What technology could I use that would allow me to stop polling the server and have the server give updated information to browser clients only when an update has actually occurred.
I would require something that provided two-way information as the browser client updates and displays information.

Comment: You should have a look into WebSocket. https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Answer (score 0):

For this type of usages we usually use web-sockets which open a "two-way" connection, we could say that the difference between http and websocket is in http you ask a question and get a response while in a websocket you have a full conversation between client and server(it's actually usually used to implement online chat apps). Image for reference:

[image: Representation of communication in a web-socket]

In your example you will open a web-socket (wss) connection to your backend and then on your frontend you will wait for the backend server to response. Since you are using Spring as a backend and javascript on the frontend you should take a look at:

- https://javascript.info/websocket
- https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring

Answer (score 0):

Both **Websockets** and **SSE** (Server Sent Events) can meet your needs.
More details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource)