# How to know a POST request was received

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have a structure where an application sends a POST request, the API handles the parameters and enters them into the database then another application that is supposed to run a function when the POST request was handled. The only issue I'm having is how can I make the 2nd application know when the request was handled other than running a GET request on a time interval?

*Another explanation:*

**Client A:** POSTs data

**API:** Handles data

**Client B:** GETs and displays data to user

How can I tell Client B when to do the GET request?

This is all in node.js and using express

Comment: You might be looking for the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). Client B would listen for events emitted by the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to push data to clients when something happens server-side. This can be achieved by either [server side events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) (which do exactly this), or [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) which create a bidirectional communication channel between server and client. Which one to choose? Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5326159/14460051) stack overflow post.